# what is the role of the comma in below statements?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, petsc

Currently reading into PETSc when I came up to this syntax in C/C++:

```
PetscInt i, n = 10, col[3], its;
PetscScalar neg_one = -1.0, one = 1.0, value[3];
```

I do not understand the meaning of the commas here. Has it to do with tuples? Or is there something overloaded?

Comment: If you think `PetscInt i,n = 10,col[3],its;` is as `(PetscInt i,n) = (10,col[3],its);`, then it's wrong. It is actually `PetscInt i,(n = 10),col[3],its;`. `= 10` is used to initialize `n`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's just declaring multiple variables of the same types.

It's like

```
int a, b;
```

The first line declares four variables of the type `PetscInt`, called `i`, `n` (which is initialized to `10`), the array `col[3]` and finally `its`. The second line declares three variables of the type `PetscScalar`.

So this:

```
PetscInt i,n = 10,col[3],its;
```

is the same as:

```
PetscInt i;
PetscInt n = 10;
PetscInt col[3];
PetscInt its;
```

Some find the original way shorter, easier to type, and also nice since it shows that the variables share (part of) the same type. Some find it confusing and/or error-prone, this is subjective of course but I felt I should mention it to kind of motivate why you often find code like this.

Comment: Oops...I actually used that syntax many times, but didn't see it in the statement because I confused it with Python's tuple assignment due to the layout. They'd better write `PetscInt i,  n=10,  col[3],  its;`

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it can be a common source of error, when someone does something like 
`int a, b=5;`  and then misreads thinking a=5.

Comment: Unfortunately they don't share the type, they share a type specifier.  If they did have the same type, such declarations wouldn't be error prone when declaring multiple pointers and/or arrays.

Comment: @2501 I tried to add the other viewpoint and also make it clear that this is subjective.

Answer (score 4):

The commas here are just to declare multiple variables **of the same type** in a single line statement. You may very well break them into one individual line, each, like

```
PetscInt i;
PetscInt n = 10;
PetscInt col[3];
PetscInt its;
```

**While both are valid and correct syntax**, some of us prefer to use the broad version anyways, as it gives a better readability (IMHO) and avoid any possible confusion while having a pointer type or storage-class specifier associated with the type.

For example, for the shorthand

```
int * p, q;
```

is the same as

```
int *p;
int q;   //not int *q
```

`q` is **not** a pointer type there.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this style should always be used. Declaring multiple variables on the same line is a well-known source for severe bugs, particularly when pointers are involved. At the same time, the code turns easier to read.

Comment: @Lundin I do agree with you sir, but the problem is, previously I was accused of "shoving" my personal opinion onto others for doing the same [ :( ], so I refrained from "suggesting" this time. Hope that does not affect the post in a negative way, right?

Comment: @Lundin However, I have expanded a bit more, trying to keep "opinon-based" content minimal, is this any good?

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to point out the dangers of the syntax. If that's too much opinion-based, then Stack Overflow definitely went crazy ;-)

Comment: I think the answer was fine to begin with, I just left the comment as recommended practice to anyone reading this.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for that and according to me, that comment is too valuable to be sitting in "comment"s section, so thought of "repairing" the answer a bit. :)